# how to insert YYMMDD + 4 digits as ID

Tags: c#, linq

In linq I knew that auto number generate is :
 `ID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();`
But I want to save my ID as YYMMDD + 4 digits.
For instance : `2015/2/12「1502120001」～[1502129999」`

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear. Please clarify your problem and add additional details and context code.
Where do you need these ids? Will you save them to the database? What should happen if you request an id more than 9999 times in one day? What should happen if the application is restarted?

Here is a very simple implementation:

```
public static class IdGenerator
{
    private static int lastId = 0;
    private static DateTime lastDate = DateTime.Now;

    public static string NewId()
    {
        // If last used date is different than today or last id is 9999 restart the counter.
        if (lastDate.Date != DateTime.Now.Date || lastId == 9999)
            lastId = 0;

        lastDate = DateTime.Now;
        return string.Format("{0:yyMMdd}{1:0000}", lastDate, ++lastId);
    }
}

// Usage
IdGenerator.NewId()
```

Note that this class doesn't guarantee unique ids if you request id more than 9999 times in one day or if application is restarted. You should use some persistent storage for last used id and last used date (not static members).

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = new Random();
string ID = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyMMdd") + random.Next(1, 9999).ToString().PadLeft(4, '0');
```

Of course with an ID generator like this, you would have to check, if an item with that ID already exists after generating a new ID and generate a new one until you find a unique one. Also you will only be able to create 9999 unique IDs, so better make sure this fits your needs.

I think you would be better off simply using Guids.